# Regex that doesn't recognise a pattern

Tags: regex

I want to make a regex that recognize some patterns and some not.

```
_*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_][^-]*.*(?<!_)
```

The sample of patterns that i want to recognize:

```
a100__version_2
_a100__version2
```

And the sample of patterns that i dont want to recognize:

```
100__version_2
a100__version2_
_100__version_2
a100--version-2
```

The regex works for all of them except this one:

```
a100--version-2
```

So I don't want to match the dashes.

I tried `_*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_][^-]*.*(?<!_)`
so the problem is at [^-]

Answer (score 1):

You could write the pattern like this, but `[^-]*` can also match newlines and spaces.

To not match newlines and spaces, and matching at least 2 characters:

```
^_*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_][^-\s]*$(?<!_)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O9XTbd/1)

Or matching only word characters, matching at least a single character repeating `\w*` zero or more times:

```
^_*[a-zA-Z]\w*$(?<!_)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `_*` Match optional underscores
- `[a-zA-Z]` Match a single char a-zA-Z
- `\w*` Match optional word chars (Or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`)
- `$` End of string
- `(?<!_)` Assert not `_` to the left at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZIbFQS/1)